# SXA LAYOUT plus image

Tags: sxa

I added a simple image to the "main" placeholder on the SXA, the image shows
But the requirement needs that this image bleeds on their borders, unfortunately, since the component It´s inside the grid, I cannot perform that
Is there any way to change that?
Thanks 
Example: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/
Here we can we the "full slider", the background in red bleeds until reach the border, can we do the same thing with the SXA Carousel ? if not, how to achieve that in the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate further.

Comment: I need create components that bleed the grid, I should probably customize the .cshtml, but I´m wondering if we have that already built in SXA in anyhow, I need to create components out of the "main" container, this will probably give me desired effect Example : https://www.napavalleyprivatelabelwine.com/assets/client/Image/bleed-sample2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of performing that 
based on this post 
[How can I make a component take up the full width of the screen?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2774/how-can-i-make-a-component-take-up-the-full-width-of-the-screen?rq=1)
I changed to "flex" and now the image is bleeding.
It changed a little bit, but this helped me to achieve the goal

The path changed to 
/sitecore/media library/Themes/Tenant/Site/Site Theme 
And there is the updated image

[image]